# Fetch substring of a field from the edge of a graph

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

I am trying fetch `substring` of field that is stored as an `attribute` in the `edge` of graph. To be more specific on the `company-company edges`

I have attached the graph creation query.

```
g.addV('company').property(id,'SHRTST01').property('name','Alphabet').next()
g.addV('company').property(id,'SHRTST02').property('name','Google').next()
g.addV('company').property(id,'SHRTST03').property('name','Youtube').next()
g.addV('company').property(id,'SHRTST05').property('name','YoutubeKids').next()
g.addV('person').property(id,'SHRTST01_1900-01-01_1_1').property('bu_id', 'SHRTST01_1900-01-01_1_1').property('name', 'W Karl David Laxton').next()
g.addV('person').property(id,'SHRTST02_1900-01-01_1_1').property('bu_id', 'SHRTST02_1900-01-01_1_1').property('name', 'Steven H Strong').next()


g.addE('HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO').from(__.V('SHRTST01')).to(__.V('SHRTST01_1900-01-01_1_1')).property(id,'SHRTST01_HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO_SHRTST01_1900-01-01_1_1').property('perc_value', 30).next()
g.addE('HAS_VOTING_PC_TO').from(__.V('SHRTST01')).to(__.V('SHRTST01_1900-01-01_1_1')).property(id,'SHRTST01_HAS_VOTING_PC_TO_SHRTST01_1900-01-01_1_1').property('perc_value', 50).next()
g.addE('HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO').from(__.V('SHRTST01')).to(__.V('SHRTST02')).property(id,'SHRTST01_HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO_SHRTST02_2002-01-01_2_2').property('perc_value', 75).next()
g.addE('HAS_VOTING_PC_TO').from(__.V('SHRTST01')).to(__.V('SHRTST02')).property(id,'SHRTST01_HAS_VOTING_PC_TO_SHRTST02_2002-01-01_2_2').property('perc_value', 50).next()
g.addE('HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO').from(__.V('SHRTST02')).to(__.V('SHRTST02_1900-01-01_1_1')).property(id,'SHRTST02_HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO_SHRTST02_1900-01-01_1_1').property('perc_value', 25).next()
g.addE('HAS_VOTING_PC_TO').from(__.V('SHRTST02')).to(__.V('SHRTST02_1900-01-01_1_1')).property(id,'SHRTST02_HAS_VOTING_PC_TO_SHRTST02_1900-01-01_1_1').property('perc_value', 23).next()
g.addE('HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO').from(__.V('SHRTST02')).to(__.V('SHRTST03')).property(id,'SHRTST02_HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO_SHRTST03_2002-01-01_2_2').property('perc_value', 80).next()
g.addE('HAS_VOTING_PC_TO').from(__.V('SHRTST02')).to(__.V('SHRTST03')).property(id,'SHRTST03_HAS_VOTING_PC_TO_SHRTST02_2003-01-01_2_2').property('perc_value', 20).next()
g.addE('HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO').from(__.V('SHRTST03')).to(__.V('SHRTST05')).property(id,'SHRTST03_HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO_SHRTST05_2002-01-01_2_2').property('perc_value', 75).next()
g.addE('HAS_VOTING_PC_TO').from(__.V('SHRTST03')).to(__.V('SHRTST05')).property(id,'SHRTST03_HAS_VOTING_PC_TO_SHRTST05_2002-01-01_2_2').property('perc_value', 30).next()
```

The below query gives me the following output but I need to refine it bit more to get the expected output.

```
g.V('SHRTST01').as('crn')
 .repeat(
  outE('HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO').as('edge_field')
 .inV()
 .simplePath())
 .until(not(outE()))
 .emit()
 .hasLabel('company')
 .select('crn','edge_field')
 .project('crn', 'edge_field')
 .by(select(keys).select('crn'))
 .by(select(keys).select('edge_field'))
```

Actual output:

```
{'crn': v[SHRTST01], 'edge_field': e[SHRTST01_HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO_SHRTST02_2002-01-01_2_2][SHRTST01-HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO->SHRTST02]}
{'crn': v[SHRTST01], 'edge_field': e[SHRTST02_HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO_SHRTST03_2002-01-01_2_2][SHRTST02-HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO->SHRTST03]}
{'crn': v[SHRTST01], 'edge_field': e[SHRTST03_HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO_SHRTST05_2002-01-01_2_2][SHRTST03-HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO->SHRTST05]}
```

Expected output:

```
{'crn': [SHRTST01], 'edge_field': [SHRTST01_HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO_SHRTST02_2002-01-01_2_2], 'shr_id':[SHRTST02_2002-01-01_2_2]}
{'crn': [SHRTST01], 'edge_field': [SHRTST02_HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO_SHRTST03_2002-01-01_2_2], 'shr_id':[SHRTST03_2002-01-01_2_2]}
{'crn': [SHRTST01], 'edge_field': [SHRTST03_HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO_SHRTST05_2002-01-01_2_2], 'shr_id':[SHRTST05_2002-01-01_2_2]}
```

I am not sure, how can I derieve the `shr_id`. As you can see, the `shr_id` is `substring` of `edge_field`. Any leads on this would be very helpful.

I am also interested to know if there is better way to handle the use case.

Thanks.

Comment: Please note that the  value of `edge_field` are slightly different in the expected and actual output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very latest release of Apache TinkerPop (3.7.1) added many new string and list operations to the Gremlin language. Once Amazon Neptune has moved up to that level of Gremlin you will easily be able to perform `substring` like operations. Until then it's probably easiest to do this in the application.

This has been a gap in Gremlin for a long time (many historical reasons) but it is great to see it now being addressed.

Those new steps are discussed here: https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/3.7.1/CHANGELOG.asciidoc#release-3-7-1

Comment: Thank you @Kelvin for clarifying the query.

Comment: One more question, is there a way to remove `v` and `e` representing `vertex` and `edge` from the output as mentioned in `actual output`.

Comment: Yes, what you are seeing there is just the "tostring" of a vertex and/or an edge. You could instead just return their ID values, using something like `by(select(keys).select('crn').id()`